# How to run SSL_library_init() from Python 3.7 docker image

Tags: python, docker, openssl

Up until recently I've been using `openssl` library within `python:3.6.6-jessie` docker image and thing worked as intented.

I'm using very basic `Dockerfile` configuration to install all necessary dependencies:

```
FROM python:3.6.6-jessie
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get install openssl
RUN apt-get upgrade -y openssl
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And access and initialize the library itself with these 2 lines:

```
openssl = cdll.LoadLibrary("libssl.so")
openssl.SSL_library_init()
```

Things were working great with this approach.

---

This week I was doing upgrade of python and libraries and as result I switched to newer docker image:

```
FROM python:3.7.5
...
```

This immediatelly caused `openssl` to stop working because of this exception:

```
AttributeError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined symbol: SSL_library_init
```

From this error I can understand that `libssl` no longer provides `SSL_library_init` method (or so it seems to be) which is rather weird issue because the initializer name in `openssl` documentation is the same.

I also tried to resolve this using `-stretch` and `-buster` distributions but the issue remains.

What is the correct approach to run `SSL_library_init` in those newer distributions? Maybe some additional dockerfile configuration is required?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install `libssl1.0-dev`

```
RUN apt-get install -y libssl1.0-dev
```